# Using GSON to parse Arraylist of ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I don't know why java has no native json parser, pretty odd, and I cam across different jars just now, like GSON, but I am still relatively new to it.

When I try to `system.out.println` my query:

```
 System.out.println(this.db.fetchAll(query));
```

I am getting this kind of list

```
[[1, user, pass], [2, another, test], [3, argh, test]]
```

How to i send this back to the browser as json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(this.db.fetchAll(query));
```

Comment: it produces `[[ ], [ ], [ ]]`, intsead of `[{ }, { }, { }]`

how to I fixe that

Comment: @JoeySalacHipolito Please look into it. I think you are getting the  correct Json string. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13992356/using-google-gson-to-convert-string-to-json-array

Comment: yeah, sorry i have mistaken